# Module aggregation in JavaScript evaluates all exports

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS file structure:

**module1.js**

```
console.log('Hello 1')
export const func1 = () => { }
```

**module2.js**

```
console.log('Hello 2')
export const func2 = () => { }
```

**index.js**

```
export * from 'module1'
export * from 'module2'
```

**app.js**

```
import {func1} from 'index'

func1()
```

In the console I can see both `Hello 1` and `Hello 2` logged. Is this intended behaviour? Will all modules be evaluated each time I import a single function from an aggregated module? And does it mean that if I want to optimize my code, I will always need to do as below?

```
import {func1} from 'module1'
import {func2} from 'module2'
```

Comment: How exactly do you run app.js? Where exactly are all the modules located? I can’t seem to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: The *module* is evaluated as soon as it imported, yes, but the *function* `func2()` is never called in your code. No, it won't log "*Hello 2*".

Comment: Actually, my simplified code was slightly inaccurate... The log statements are in the modules **outside** of the exported functions. Updated the question.

Comment: Uh, yes, the edited code is _substantially_ different. Of course these two log calls will be executed.

Comment: "*Does it mean that if I want to optimize my code, I will always need to do as below?*" - what exactly do you want to optimise? Is there a problem with evaluating all imported modules?

Comment: Thanks. And just to understand this better, in a project with a bundler like webpack, would my build package include the entire module 2 if I only import a function from module 1 via the aggregated module?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: Thanks for the link Bergi. I am indeed aware of tree-shaking, I just wanted someone more experienced than me to confirm that in the case as described the tree would indeed be "shaken" and in a production build func2 would not be bundled.

Comment: Well if you actually have a `console.log()` statement in that module, it won't get shaken away - so avoid that. But the exported `func2` declaration that is not imported anyway can be eliminated, yes.